# How to execute vim internal global commands with this setup?

Tags: vim

I have something like the below in my `.vimrc` on MacOSx El Capitan.

```
let g:plantuml_executable_script='java -jar /Users/megan/Downloads/plantuml.jar'
```

To be sure Java is available I typed `which java` on the command line and I got `/usr/bin/java`, so I have that added to `$PATH`.

Now, when I do the following in Vim by opening up a plantuml file:

```
:! java -jar /Users/megan/Downloads/plantuml.jar
```

I get a nice class diagram image generated.

What could I do in Vim so that I can type `plantuml_executable_script` instead and get the nice diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/) (please let me know if I'm wrong).  If it's so [this](http://plantuml.com/starting.html) webpage can get you started.

Let's say you're editing a file called `sequenceDiagram.txt` which has the following lines:

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: test
@enduml
```

and then you save it with `:w` command. After that you can execute:

```
:!java -jar /Users/megan/Documents/plantuml.jar %
```

to get a file called `sequenceDiagram.png`. Note that Vim will replace `%` at the end of the command line with the file name you're editing.

Now, if you want a command called `plantuml_executable_script` to execute `:!java -jar /Users/megan/Documents/plantuml.jar %`, you can create it by executing:

```
:command! PlantUMLExecutableScript !java -jar /Users/megan/Documents/plantuml.jar %
```

Please note:

- An uppercase`P` was used because user-defined commands must start with a capital letter.
- Underscores cannot be used.
- See  [`:help 40.2`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.2) and [`:help user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands) for more information.

In that way you can execute `:PlantUMLExecutableScript` to run PlantUML. But you can go one better by creating a mapping:

```
:noremap <F2> :PlantUMLExecutableScript<CR>
```

So you can hit <kbd>F2</kbd> (or whatever key you choose)  to call `:PlantUMLExecutableScript`. See [`:help 05.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#05.3), [`:help 40.1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.1) and [`:help key-mapping`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#key-mapping) for more information.